# What am I doing wrong? (using the formula for lowering powers)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$cos^2x sin^2x$$

$$(\frac { 1+cos2x }{ 2 } )(\frac { 1-cos2x }{ 2 } )$$

$$(\frac { 1-cos^{ 2 }2x }{ 4 } )$$

$$(\frac { 1-\frac { 1+cos2(2x) }{ 2 }  }{ 4 } )(\frac { 2 }{ 2 } )$$

$$\frac { 2-1+cos4x }{ 8 } $$

$$\frac { 1+cos4x }{ 8 } $$

Where am I going wrong that I end up with this answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dropped a minus sign

$$(\frac { 1-\frac { 1+\cos (2\cdot 2x) }{ 2 }  }{ 4 } )(\frac { 2 }{ 2 } )$$

$$\frac { 2-1-\cos(4x) }{ 8 } $$

Comment: the minus in front of the fraction has to be distributed?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Exactly

Comment: That is something that I always miss. Now why doesn't the distribution of the negative sign extend to the $2(2x)$ in cosine

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Because $\cos(4x)$ is one object, and also $-\cos(4x) \neq cos(-4x)$